# backbonejs menu from models belonging to different collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am developing a Backbonejs app using the excellent Marionette plugin.
I have a big navigation view consisting of `<a>` tags referencing various collections. An example will better explain this:

- Cars

  - Car A
  - ...
  - Car Z
- Books

  - Book A
  - ...
  - Book Z

Each block is a collection of models. Eg. `CarList`, `BookList`

How do i best architect the Menuview so that, whenever any of the model changes in any of the collection the Menu view is rerendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use a `Composite View` for your menu view and a `Collection View` for every sub-folder of your menu. Composite and Collection Views are made in a way that they will add/remove automatically a child element when a model is added/remove to the collection.

For more information you can check here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/